# CORS issue with Ionic on localhost and on device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cors

I have an Ionic project that is making API calls to my database in Azure and an external API. I keep getting CORS errors:

Error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

I have read online that this can happen in the browser, but the issue is that I am also having this issue when I have installed the app through an apk. Furthermore, the strangest thing is that I am having this error roughly 10% of the time. This means I can perform all my GET and POST requests one minute, and then the next minute I keep getting these errors. I have no clue how this error can only be triggered sometimes so it would be great if someone know how to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to create a network_security_config.xml file in your native android project android/app/src/main/res/xml directory with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
      <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
      </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

then add this: `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config` in your AndroidManifest.xml file to look something like this:

```
<application 
             android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" 
             android:allowBackup="true" 
             android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
             android:label="@string/app_name" 
             android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" 
             android:supportsRtl="true" 
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

alternatively, instead of using HTTPClient (angular), you can use the platform-native HTTP library which you can find here: https://github.com/capacitor-community/http if you are using Capacitor, or https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http if you are using Cordova and you will not have CORS issues any longer.